# How to private swagger document?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger (on NodeJS, swagger-ui-express) to document my API.

This is how I build swagger server and setup my document on server

```
app.use('/apidocs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(getSwaggerSpec()));
```

But now I need to private or set permission for someone in the team can access to document, and I expect all outside person can't access to my document

I tried with adding a middleware, but I didn't work.

```
  app.use('/apidocs', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.userName === 'admin' && req.query.password === '12345678') {
      console.log('-=-=-')
      next();
    } else {
      res.send('Unauthenticated');
    }
  }, swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(getSwaggerSpec()));
```

Code is fine. But when I access with exactly userName and password. It show a white page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try to use an access token ?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const authToken = '123456';
app.use('/apidocs', (req, res) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || '';
  const match = authHeader.match(/Bearer (.+)/);
  const token = match[1];
  if (token !== authToken) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  } else {
    return HERE YOUR RESPONSE
  }
});
```

also you could to use express basics auth  [https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth]

```
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

app.use("/api-docs",basicAuth({
    users: {'yourUser': 'yourPassword'},
    challenge: true,
}), swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

Comment: I not catch up your mean? Actually, when user try to request api with try it out button, they have to provide a token. But, I want to authenticate before user can see my document.

Comment: Sorry, I edited  my answer!

Comment: what the difference between my middleware :v

Comment: Why is login form showed only one time? When I access at 2nd time, it's not showed up